# Reducing the space between the reference number and the list

Tags: biblatex, spacing

I am using `biblatex` and I would like to reduce the space between the reference number and the corresponding entry in the reference list. See the screenshot below.
[image]

I am calling `biblatex` with those options, and I am also changing the style of the references (with parenthesis, and superscript inside the text) :

```latex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-numeric,sorting=none,doi=false,minbibnames=1,maxbibnames=1,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=1,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{supercite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelimsAlias{cite}{supercite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\let\cite=\supercite
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between numeric citation label and the rest of the entry is controlled by the length `\biblabelsep`. Its default value is `2\labelsep`.

You get a smaller space if you go for just `\labelsep` (but of course you can pick any value).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric, sorting=none, doi=false, minnames=1, maxnames=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{supercite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelimsAlias{cite}{supercite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Reduced space between numeric citation label and entry.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is what I was looking for!